# Вычисление значение функции

Tags: python

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возможно это нагло, но честно, я сидел над этим заданием неделю. Я пока ученик и пытаюсь разобраться с этим. Не могли бы Вы мне с ним помочь. Могу скинуть наработки, но оно все не верно и не то. Буду благодарен за помощь в решении. Извините меня(

```
x=int(input("Введите целое число:"))
if x>=4:
    s=f"{x}>=4"
    print(s)
else:
    print('Ошибка! Неверное значение функции')

if x**3-x**2:
    s=f"2<={x}<4"
    print(s)
else:
    print('Ошибка! Неверное значение функции')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Нужно оформить код в виде функции
2. Проверять нужно условия во второй колонке задания, затем вычислять выражение в первой колонке
3. После вычисления результата возврат значения функции производится с помощью `return`

```
def y(x):
    if x >= 4:
        return 1
    elif 2 <= x < 4:
        return x ** 3 - x ** 2
    elif 1 <= x < 2:
        return x ** 2 + x
    else:
        return -1


x = int(input("Введите целое число:"))
print(y(x))
```

```
Введите целое число:3
18
```

Comment: Благодарю за решение)